# Scala: enforcing precedence of an implicit declared in a trait

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-implicits

There are countless questions on this topic and a quite good, if not very precisely worded article here: [Revisiting implicits without the import tax](http://eed3si9n.com/revisiting-implicits-without-import-tax). I've read most of them, but have a problem with overriding default `CanBuildFrom` implicits without repeating the declarations myself. If you're familiar with scala collection library and resolution of `CanBuildFrom`, you know that for every scala collection trait `CC[X]`, its companion object defines an implicit `CanBuildFrom[CC[_], X, CC[X]]` instance. I have introduced my own collection hierarchy, rooted in a class derived from `IndexedSeq[X]`:

```
trait SpecSeq[X] extends IndexedSeq[X]
trait MutableSeq[X] extends SpecSeq[X]
trait ConstSeq[X] extends SpecSeq[X]
trait ArraySeq[X] extends MutableSeq[X]
trait ConstArray[X] extends ConstSeq[X]
```

Can I avoid declaring implicit values in companion objects of all defined traits and instead extract them to a common base trait for the companion objects? 
I tried having:

```
trait SpecCompanion[S[X]<:SpecSeq[X]] {
    implicit def canBuildFrom[X] :CanBuildFrom[S[_], X, S[X]] = ???
}
ArraySeq extends SpecCompanion[ArraySeq]
ConstArray extends SpecCompanion[ConstArray]
...
```

Unfortunately, those definitions aren't considered more specific than the one declared in `object IndexedSeq`. This issue is aggreviated by the fact that in reality it's not a single implicit value, but several with increasing level of requirements for `X`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a layer of indirection and my own sublass of `CanBuildFrom`:

```
trait SpecCanBuildFrom[-F, -E, +T] extends CanBuildFrom[F, E, T]

trait SpecCompanion[S[X]<:SpecSeqw[X]] {
    implicit def cbf[X] :SpecCanBuildFrom[S[_], X, S[S]] = ???
}

object SpecSeq extends SpecCompanion[SpecSeq] {
    implicit def canBuildFrom[C[X]<:SpecSeq[X], X](implicit ev :SpecCanBuildFrom[C[_], X, C[X]) :CanBuildFrom[C[_], X, C[X]] = ev
}

object ArraySeq extends SpecCompanion[ArraySeq]
object ConstArray extends SpecCompanion[ConstArray]
```

Now the generic definition in SpecSeq overrides all implicits in scala collections.

Good enough, but I wonder if it is possible to do it directly.